# How do I start learning play framework with scala from scratch?

Tags: macos, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to learn scala and I want to build a  web application using play framework. How set up the environment in mac and how to start?

Comment: I would say this is not the best place to ask, and I would recommend you to ask on the scala subreddit at https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/

Comment: I'd also recommend looking at those templates: https://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates. Most of them come with a little tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is not the best place to ask, and I would recommend you to ask on the scala subreddit at https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/

Nevertheless make sure you have:

- sbt installed. Documentation at http://www.scala-sbt.org/
- Follow the Play framework tutorials https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Installing
- Find some tutorials online. I wrote one, a while ago: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/
- I also recommend a good IDE as Intellij at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/